# Shell: sed - replace a text from specific number range

Tags: regex, bash, shell, replace, sed

I have a following problem:

sed -e "s/[theText] [someNumber]/$var2/"

I have a number next to the text. 
I need to do following - if the number is between 5 and 20, replace the string with $var2, else do nothing. Is there any possibility to do this directly in sed without using loops? I've tried constructions like *theText [5-20]2* but it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because sed does not understand arithmetic, sed is not the ideal tool here.  The following, however, will do what you ask:

```
sed -Ee "s/some text ([5-9]|1[0-9]|20)$/$var2/"
```

Or, if you want to stick to basic regex:

```
sed -e "s/some text \([5-9]\|1[0-9]\|20\)$/$var2/"
```

The above looks for the text, followed by a space, followed by one of `[5-9]` or `1[0-9]` or `20`, followed by the end of the line, `$`.

Since sed does not understand math, there is no way to specify a numeric range like `5-20`.

Be sure that you trust the source of `var2`.  Putting `$var2` into a sed command like that is a security issue because it enables execution of arbitrary commands.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What do you recommend to do in general? Because the interval is dynamic (I use a variable as first number, 5-20 was just for illustration). It could be 1-20 or even 18-20. I though about using loops (repeat 20 - N times, in each iteration replace one of the number in the range).
Note: Do not care about security, it is a script for internal use only :)

Comment: @melonsvk Awk is probably the right tool for this: it can do substitutions and it understands math.

Comment: Worth noting the `-E` flag from BSD sed is equivalent to the `-r` flag in GNU sed.

Comment: @miken32 Yes.  But note that modern versions of GNU sed support `-E` as a synonym for `-r`.  Also, rumor has it that `-E` will become the POSIX choice.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{match($0,/some text ([0-9]*)/,a); 
        if(a[1]+0>5 && a[1]+0<20) 
            sub(/some text/,"replacement")}1' << EOF
> some text 100
> some text 10
> EOF
```

will print

```
some text 100
replacement 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I started splitting the string and the number, but making the solution work becomes a mess:

```
lower=4
upper=88
matchstring="MyText"

echo "Example testing substring MyText followed by number 4 until 88"
read -p "Give your teststring "  str
if [[ ${str} = ^${matchstring}* ]]; then
    echo "Nope, no match with ${matchstring}"
else
    echo "Matching ${str#${matchstring}}"
    if [[ "${str#${matchstring}}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
       echo "it is a number..."
       if [ ${str#${matchstring}} -ge ${lower} ] &&
          [ ${str#${matchstring}} -le ${upper} ]; then
          echo "Bingo !"
       else
          echo "Not in range (${lower},${upper})"
       fi
    else
       echo "No number"
    fi
fi
```

But this script can be improved by combining the first 2 tests:

```
lower=4
upper=88
matchstring="MyText"

echo "Example testing substring MyText followed by number 4 until 88"
read -p "Give your teststring "  str
if [[ ${str} =~ ^${matchstring}[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "Nope, You should use ${matchstring}123"
else
    if [ ${str#${matchstring}} -ge ${lower} ] &&
       [ ${str#${matchstring}} -le ${upper} ]; then
       echo "Bingo !"
    else
       echo "Not in range (${lower},${upper})"
    fi
fi
```

The main reason I still do not like it is because it is hard to read.
You can introduce an extra variable `theNumber=${str#${matchstring}}`, just to make it easier to read when you test `theNumber` against the limits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Bash` and `grep`, to grab the number portion and test it before using `sed` for the substitution:

```
HIGH=350 
LOW=100 
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for a in $(< yourfile.txt); do 
VAR=$(grep -o "[0-9]*$" <<< "${a}")
((${VAR} < ${HIGH})) && ((${VAR} > ${LOW})) && sed "s/${a}/${var2}/"
done
```

Change the HIGH, LOW values to whatever ranges you would like. I think this may be a bit more readable/maintainable than an `awk` script, but `awk` could also handle this.